# Why does this loop have only one iteration instead of the number of iterations entered by the user?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, input

I am trying to ask the user to enter any number and then ask the user to enter any names, then store this input in a list.

However, when I enter any number, it asks to enter name only one time and shows the output in list:

```
def main():
    # a = 4
    a = input("Enter number of players: ")
    tmplist = []
    i = 1
    for i in a:
        pl = input("Enter name: " )
        tmplist.append(pl)
        
    print(tmplist)

if __name__== "__main__": 
    main()
```

output:

```
Enter number of players: 5
Enter name: Tess
['Tess']
```

The `for` loop should run 5 times and user entered 5 values get stored in a list.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python) would be a better duplicate in terms of popularity and detail, but neither one addresses the lack of `range`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert the number of players to integer and then loop for that much amount of times, you can use the [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function for this . Example -

```
def main():
    num=int(input("Enter number of players: "))
    tmplist=[]
    for _ in range(num):
        pl=input("Enter name: " )
        tmplist.append(pl)

    print(tmplist)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you tell me why range is used here?

Comment: @PrafullaKamble - You really should review your textbook or other course materials (or, if you're not in a class, the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html)). Your code shows that you're missing several fundamental concepts.

Comment: thanks. Rather than using append - is there any other way to add values to a list?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using Python3

```
a=input("Enter number of players: ")
```

means `a` is a string "5". Since this is only one character long - the loop will run just once

You need to use

```
a = int(input("Enter number of players: "))
```

You'll also need to change the loop

```
for i in range(a):
```

I recommend using more meaningful variable names - especially if this is homework

```
def main():
    number_of_players = int(input("Enter number of players: "))
    player_list = []

    for i in range(number_of_players):
        player = input("Enter name: " )
        player_list.append(player)

    print(player_listlist)

if __name__== "__main__": 
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the input a is a string
you need to convert it to a number and then use a different for.

it should be

```
def main():
    #a=4
    a=int(input("Enter number of players: "))
    tmplist=[]
    i=0
    while i < a:
        pl=input("Enter name: ")
        tmplist.append(pl)
        i+=1
    print(tmplist)

main()
```

Comment: OP is using Python 3, so please replace `raw_input("Enter name: ")` with `input('Enter name: ')`.

Comment: @Srgrn
tried this one but it goes into infinite loop.

Comment: I tested it on python 2 so maybe i missed something, I see you were helped anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You got a string `a` which presumably contained something like `'5'`. Then you initialize a counter `i`. Then you loop through this string, which, since it's `'5'`, resulted in one iteration, because there's only one character in `'5'`.

First you have to change it into a number, with `a = int(a)`.

With `a` as a number, you still can't loop through that, because a number isn't an iterable.

So then you should create a `range` object to loop over, with `for i in range(a):`.

Then you will be able to carry out your operations as expected.